# dynamic button Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have dynamic table with input button like this:

```
<div id="pesertakegiatan">
<button id="simpan" value="Simpan" style="float:right;" class="push_button blue">Simpan Kegiatan</button>
<input id="idkegiatan1" name="idkegiatan1" value="1" type="hidden">
    <table id="tablehasil" class="display" style="width:100%;">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nama</th>
                <th>AKD</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    <?php
    $dsql="select * from tabel_anggota order by id asc";
    $dquery=mysql_query($dsql);
    while($dassoc=mysql_fetch_assoc($dquery)){
        $nama=$dassoc['NAMA'];
        $id=$dassoc['ID'];

        echo'
            <tr class="pesertaAcara">
                <td>'.$nama.'</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="akdanggota" name="akdanggota"> ';
                        $sqlcariakd="select b.ID, b.NAMA_AKD from akd_anggota a, tabel_akd b where a.id_anggota='$id' and a.id_akd=b.id";
                        $qcariakd=mysql_query($sqlcariakd);
                        while($rowk=mysql_fetch_assoc($qcariakd)){
                            $idakdnya=$rowk['ID'];
                            $namaakdnya=$rowk['NAMA_AKD'];
                            echo'
                                <option value="'.$idakdnya.'">'.$namaakdnya.'</option>
                            ';
                        }
        echo    '   </select>

                </td>
                <td><button class="inputpst" onclick>Input</button></td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
    ?>
</div>
```

and

```
$('.inputpst').click(function() {
    var akda = $(this).parents("tr").find(".akdanggota").val
    var ida = $(this).val();
    var idkeg = $('#idkegiatan1').val();
    var aksi = "akdnya"

    $.ajax({  
            url:"inputacara.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data: {
            idkeg:idkeg,
            ida:ida,
            akda:akda,
            aksi:aksi
        },  
            success:function(response){
                alert("sukses");
            }      
        });
});
```

what I want is when I click the input button then the existing data on the row will be entered into the database, but when i click on input button i got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

I am using `jquery-1.12.4.min.js`

Comment: change `var akda = $(this).parents("tr").find(".akdanggota").val` to `var akda = $(this).parents("tr").find(".akdanggota").val()`

Comment: The code you posted doesn't call `toLowerCase`; it seems very likely you've posted the wrong code. Also, 1.12.4 is pretty old at this point. Also, check @B.Desai's comment; it may well be your solution.

Comment: @B.Desai thanks, it solved my problem, i forgot to add () after .val

Comment: @EdCottrell, i find toLowerCase on jquery-1.12.4.min.js

Comment: @Gumilar I didn't say it isn't used in jQuery. I said your code didn't include any use of it. It's extremely difficult to solve problems if people don't post all relevant information (such as stating in the question that your code doesn't use that method). In any case, I'm glad you solved your problem.